# Creating a push notification system with a React Native front end and a Java Spring back end?

Tags: ios, spring-boot, react-native, push-notification

Currently building a mobile application that ideally would have functionality that allows one user to "nudge" another user, pretty much the equivalent to a Facebook "poke." For the sake of building quickly, we'd like to use as many third-party libraries/services as possible. So far we were looking into using pusher and expo, but to be totally honest, we are a bit confused as to how to architecture this.

From what I understand, the front-end (ios app) would subscribe (open a socket) to a specific channel/server and the server would then send messages to the client(s) that subscribed whenever necessary. How this works with users being subscribed to every other user they are friends with, I don't understand. What's the proper way to architecture this?

I also read that on the front end, when a user doesn't have the ios application open you can't have any websockets open to the server, so how does that work?

Additionally, how does one bundle notifications??

Really confused with this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, push notifications now mostly are implemented with Firebase. This is a service inside most of mobiles, so you only need use these libraries to implement your client application.

From the server, you only need to consume a rest api of Firebase.

Now there are permissions to allow mobile applications receive push notifications in background. You do not need to implement a socket or websocket, that is a feature of Firebase.

Read more about this.

[https://medium.com/google-cloud/push-notification-for-react-native-bef05ea4d1d0](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-push-notifications-on-firebase-cloud-me)

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-push-notifications-on-firebase-cloud-me